# Geodesic equation (free particle)

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, geodesics

How to find a coordinate system whose geodesic equation does not have the "Christoffel symbol" term? (i.e. free particle - generalized Newton's second law.)

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/91348/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Can you add more details? You can't always choose a coordinate system where the geodesic equation is trivial everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you're in a coordinate system where the Christoffels don't vanish at some point.

To choose a coordinate system where the Christoffel symbols vanish at a given point $p$, you must apply a [Christoffel symbol change of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christoffel_symbols#Change_of_variable):

$$0={\bar\Gamma}^k{}_{ij} =
\frac{\partial x^p}{\partial y^i}\,
\frac{\partial x^q}{\partial y^j}\,
\Gamma^r{}_{pq}\,
\frac{\partial y^k}{\partial x^r}
+ 
\frac{\partial y^k}{\partial x^m}\, 
\frac{\partial^2 x^m}{\partial y^i \partial y^j}$$

For simplicity, maybe $\frac{\partial x^a}{\partial y^b}=\delta^a_b$ (evaluated at point $p$ and point p only, so this says nothing about the second derivatives), in which case the equation becomes:

$$0=
\Gamma^k_{ij}
+  
\frac{\partial^2 x^k}{\partial y^i \partial y^j}$$

if $x^k=y^k+C^k_{i j} y^i y^j$ and $p$ is the origin, this tells you immediately that if you choose $C^k_{ij}=-\Gamma^k_{ij}$ then you're in a frame where all of the Christoffels vanish.

Comment: It is possible to improve this result, obtaining $\Gamma_{ij}^k=0$ all along a timelike geodesic in a suitable coordinate system defined in a open tube centered on the geodesic. This is a better mathematical description of the equivalence principle than the coordinate system in the answer (mentioned in Landau-Lifsits' textbook). This is because here the "gravitational field" is (approximately) cancelled in a *free falling* coordinate system (the one constructed in the mentioned tube around the timelike geodesic) and not only  around a fixed event.

Comment: @ValterMoretti Are you referring to Fermi coordinates?

Comment: I do not think so, I as far as I remember Fermi coordinates also include the notion of *non-rotating frame*, here unnecessary. I simply referred to so-called normal (or Gaussian) coordinates adapted to a submanifold, the graph of the geodesic in this case. The construction is elementary, it can be found, e.g. in O'Neill's textbook...