# Conformal time-like Killing vector near null geodesics in all spacetimes?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, vector-fields, geodesics

Is it true that in *all* spacetimes there is some conformal time-like Killing vector $\tau^a$ in the *vicinity* of null geodesics?

If the above statement is true then can one argue that, *for all spacetimes*, an EM wave propagating along a null geodesic with wave-vector $k^a$ has a conserved quantity $k_a\tau^a=k_\tau$?

Please see @MichaelSeifert's informative answer and comments for background to Killing vectors, conserved quantities and EM waves:

https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/186483/22307

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what motivated this question?

Comment: I am wondering if it is generally true that photons propagate with constant energy with respect to conformal time. I am interested in the case of FRW cosmology where this might imply that photon energy density $\rho_{rad}\propto 1/a^3$ rather than the conventional $1/a^4$.