# Does the total particle energy increase in FRW Universe?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, space-expansion

If a particle travels on a geodesic with 4-momentum $P^\mu$ in a spacetime with a Killing vector $K_\mu$ then we have a constant of motion, $K$, given by:
$$K=K_\mu P^\mu$$
Using the relationships:
$$P^\mu=mU^\mu$$
and
$$K_\mu=g_{\mu\nu}K^\nu$$
we obtain:
$$K=mg_{\mu\nu}K^\nu U^\mu$$
Let us assume that $K^\nu$ is a timelike Killing vector so that we have:
$$K^\nu=(1,0,0,0)$$
Then the constant $K$ is the total energy $e$ of the particle (including gravitational energy) given by:
$$e=-mg_{00}\frac{dt}{d\tau}$$
The above argument is my generalisation from @StanLiou's [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/45170/22307) to the question [Potential Energy in General Relativity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/45145/potential-energy-in-general-relativity) where he gives an expression for the total energy of a particle in geodesic motion in Schwarzschild spacetime. I hope I have got the algebra correct!

My question is: could this definition of total particle energy be carried over to cosmology where one has the FRW metric?

The FRW metric does not have a timelike Killing vector so that one cannot expect the total energy $e$ of a co-moving particle to be constant. But the FRW metric does have a timelike *conformal* Killing vector so that it seems reasonable that the particle energy should scale in some way with conformal time $\eta$.

We can write the flat FRW metric in conformal co-ordinates:
$$ds^2=a(\eta)^2(-d\eta^2+dx^2+dy^2+dz^2)$$
Thus we have:
$$g_{00}=-a(\eta)^2$$
$$\frac{d\eta}{d\tau}=\frac{1}{a(\eta)}$$
Therefore
$$e=m\ a(\eta)$$
Thus it seems that the total energy of a co-moving particle, when expressed in conformal co-ordinates, scales with the Universal scale factor $a(\eta)$.

Is this reasoning valid?

Comment: what about the redshift ?

Comment: The redshift would be due to observers' clocks running faster with respect to conformal time as the Universe expands. See one of @MichaelSeifert's replies in http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/186483/22307. (I think he meant clocks run *faster* rather than slower).

Comment: at least , redshift decreases the radiation energy as universe expands... I don't understand the last calculation.

Comment: Perhaps the radiation energy actually stays constant and it's the observer's energy which is increasing, with respect to conformal time.

Comment: I don't agree ou disagree , this question is very interesting, I was about to post a similar one. Could you please detail the calculation ?

Comment: Sorry - which calculation are you referring to?

Comment: how you found $e=m a(η)$ ...