# Is Energy conserved in General Relativity

Tags: general-relativity, energy, energy-conservation, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I have seen a few posts here on stack exchange that suggest that energy is not conserved in general relativity on a large scale.

I am a pretty confused with this. I don’t understand how such a conclusion is reached.

$\nabla_\mu T^{\mu\nu}$ $=0$

Doesn’t the above equation signify that energy momentum is conserved in GR.

Please note there are other questions already on such issues. But they seem to suggest that energy is not conserved in GR.

See for eg: [If the energy of the photon is conserved along a geodesic why is it redshifted](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/605818/113699)

But I am asking that when we have $\nabla_\mu T^{\mu\nu}$ $=0$ **why will energy not be conserved in the first place itself**

Edit after the comment:

**I am asking why $\nabla_\mu T^{\mu\nu}$ $=0$ does not imply energy conservation**

Comment: I am not familiar with the mathematics of GR, but is the above equation true *between* reference frames or only in one reference frame?

Comment: @Jonas It is an equation so it’s valid in an reference frame. If I had a partial derivative instead of a covariant derivative then it would have been valid in just an inertial frame.

Comment: This question is already answered in the link you provide. This question should be closed.

Comment: @Oбжорoв Read the question again. I know that a conserved quantity can be constructed from a killing vector. I am asking why the vanishing of covariant derivative of energy momentum tensor not imply energy conservation.

Comment: Also possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2597, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/109532

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/306838/2451 and links therein.

Comment: A proper conservation law means $\partial_{a} T^{ab}=0$. The covariant conservation law isn't really a conservation law in the sense you're talking about because it's implicitly related to the gravitational field. In other words, $\nabla_{a}  T^{ab}=0$ also describes the transfer of energy between the gravitational field (not included in $T^{ab}$) and the energy of $T^{ab}$.

Comment: @Eletie I vaguely understand what you are saying in your comment. I guess things would be clearer if the explanation is expanded a bit. If you would like to put and answer, I will be glad to accept it.